# Application is crashing on facebook in apple review

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, crash-reports

We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

Specifically, your app still crashed on launch after the user logged in with facebook.

I m unable to catch the crash or any error.
Here's the code for where I think it's crashing (run right after users log in with Facebook)

```
@IBAction func Btn_facebook(_ sender: Any)
{
    getFacebookUserInfo()
}

func getFacebookUserInfo()
{
    let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()

    fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile","email"], from: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil)
        {
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result!
            // if user cancel the login
            if (result?.isCancelled)!{
                return
            }
            if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
            {
                self.getFBUserData()
                self.fbtoken = result!.token.tokenString

            }
        }
    }
}

func getFBUserData()
{
    if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil)
    {
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, email, picture"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if result != nil {

                guard FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString != nil else {
                    debugPrint("failed to get access token")
                    return
                }

                guard let result = result as? NSDictionary, let user_id_fb = result["id"]  as? String else {
                    print("error")

                    return
                }

            }

            if (error == nil)
            {

                let fbDetails = result as! NSDictionary

                let field = result! as? [String:Any]
                if let imageURL = ((field!["picture"] as? [String: Any])?["data"] as? [String: Any])?["url"] as? String {
                    print(imageURL)
                    let url = URL(string: imageURL)
                    print(url!)
                    self.fburl = imageURL
                    print(self.fburl!)

                }
                let checkemail = fbDetails["email"] as? String

                if(checkemail != nil)
                {
                    print(" check email not nil ", checkemail as Any)

                    self.fbemail = (fbDetails["email"] as? String)
                    self.fbid = (fbDetails["id"] as? String)
                    self.fbname = (fbDetails["name"] as? String)

                    self.GandfLogin(name: self.fbname!, email: self.fbemail!, post_image: (self.fburl!))
                }
                else
                {
                    print(" check email nil ",checkemail ?? String.self)

                    self.fbid = (fbDetails["id"] as? String)
                    self.fbname = (fbDetails["name"] as? String)

                    self.GandfLogin(name: self.fbname!, email: self.fbid!, post_image: (self.fburl!))
                }

            }
            else
            {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Not found")
            }
        })




    }
}
```

Comment: Apple have provided a crash log.  This will contain an exception message and a stack trace that you can symbolicate to determine where the crash occurred.  In general you should avoid force unwrapping optionals (e.g. `result!`, `self.fbName!` etc)

Comment: sir if i use this (e.g result as Any , self.fbName as Any).

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `as Any`. You should use `as? String` (or whatever the appropriate type is) along with `if let` or `guard let` or `??` as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Use soft unwraps instead of ! in most cases 
Because it can lead to crashes if Facebook does not send data which you a looking for back

Do it this way:

```
guard let fbDetails = result as NSDictionary else {
  //Show error to user or something else
  return
}
```